# How can I make this if's work in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In bash how can I make a construction like this to work:

```
if (cp /folder/path /to/path) && (cp /anotherfolder/path /to/anotherpath)
then
  echo "Succeeded"
else
  echo "Failed"
fi
```

The if should test for the $? return code of each command and tie them with &&.

How can I make this in Bash ?

Comment: @Dragos, lose the parentheses; all they do is spawn an extra subshell (almost certainly not what you want.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
if cp /folder/path /to/path /tmp && cp /anotherfolder/path /to/anotherpath ;then
  echo "ok"
else
  echo "not"
fi
```

Comment: @Dragos, the courteous next step is to formally accept one of these answers.

Answer (score 8):

```
cp /folder/path /to/path && cp /anotherfolder/path /to/anotherpath
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
    echo "Succeeded"
else
    echo "Failed"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you,
$? is the last cp return code not the entire operation ? So is it correct ?

Comment: @Dragos: The last command, a *complex* command in this case, it the `cp && cp`. If the first exits non-zero $? gets that. If the second exits non-zero then $? gets that. Otherwise $? gets zero (and both exited zero). But this is a useless use of $? since the commands can be put directly in the `if`.

Comment: @Chris, technically it is called a **pipeline** IIRC, not a "complex" command. :)

Comment: @Vlad, there is no pipe (`|`) involved. My “complex command” comes from the *dash* manual. http://linux.die.net/man/1/dash Other sets of documentation (POSIX: http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html ; and *bash*: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists ) do not include the same idea of a “complex” command. The `one && two` construct is called a list command consistently though.

Comment: Sorry, yes, "list" is what I was looking for.  I'll take the POSIX nomenclature over `dash` any time. :)

Answer (score 2):

Another way :

```
cp /folder/path /to/path && cp /anotherfolder/path /to/anotherpath && {
  echo "suceeded"
} || {
  echo "failed"
}
```

I tested it :

```
david@pcdavid:~$ cp test.tex a && cp test.aux b && { echo "haha"; } || { echo "hoho"; }
haha
david@pcdavid:~$ cp test.ztex a && cp test.aux b && { echo "haha"; } || { echo "hoho"; }
cp: cannot stat `test.ztex': No such file or directory
hoho
david@pcdavid:~$ cp test.tex a && cp test.zaux b && { echo "haha"; } || { echo "hoho"; }
cp: cannot stat `test.zaux': No such file or directory
hoho
```